# Command line to switch from user session to console session

Tags: windows-server-2003, mstsc

Windows Server 2003

If I already RDP to a remote host with user session, is there any command that I can switch to console session without closing current session and re-RDP again with "mstsc /console" parameter? Thanks.

**EDIT:**
After RDP to the remote host with session ID 1, there are 2 cases.
1. session 0 is created, so I can right click and connect to that session. Is there any command line to do the same?
2. session 0 is not created. Is there a command line to do the same too?

And I need to switch back and forth.

[image]

Comment: Need a little more info from you.  This server is in terminal server mode, correct (as opposed to admin mode)?  If so, there should be no problem connecting as a user, minimizing that and then connecting with a console session.  Are you looking for a command to switch back and forth or something?

Answer (score 1):

The `shadow` command can be used to shadow a session on Windows 2003 Server. You might use this to interact with the console session when logged in with a user session.

Comment: shadow seems not working for the case when console session is not being created in advance.

Comment: Yes, that is true. But a work-around could be to have a user logged in to the console session at all times. Then you should be able to shadow it. I'm not sure you will find any command that lets you switch directly to the console session in Win 2k3.